# Jquery Ajax Json testing locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a form and a api but i dont know how to test if if the data is saved as a json, can anyone help me ?

```
<form id="reg-form" method="post" action="">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="yourname">Please enter your name :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yourname" name="yourname" placeholder="Name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="surname">Please enter your surname :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="genderType">Gender</label>
    <div class="styledropdownwarp">
        <select class="form-control" name="genderType" id="genderType" required>
            <option value="">Gender</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my api below, I want to send this form data in another url but first i want to test it localy if it works maybe send the form data as a json to another page or view them in console. Any Ideas ?

```
console.log(document);
var form = document.getElementById("reg-form");

form.onsubmit = function (e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var data = {};
  for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    var input = form[i];
    if (input.name) {
      data[input.name] = input.value;
    }
  }
  addData();
}

function addData(){
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://192.168.100.11:8443/v1/captive-portal/device-registration",
         data: JSON.stringify(data),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         crossDomain: true,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

             alert(success);
         },

         error: function (jqXHR, status) {
             // error handler
             console.log(jqXHR);
             alert('fail' + status.code);
         }
      });
}
```

Comment: press `ctrl+shift+j` in chrome to open dev tools. now go to `network` tab and send the request... You will see the xhr request sent to server. Now click on the request and check sent data by scrolling to bottom. This is the exact data that that the server will receive.

Comment: If you want to see it in the console first, comment out the `$.ajax()` request and do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` in the `addData()` function. Your JSON will show up in the console then.

Comment: I did the following but I still dont get anything in the console.log did you suggest me to do this:

    function addData(){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}

Comment: Yes, but you also need to pass the `data` variable like `addData(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your requirement is for some tool to test the API methods that you have created to build the app. You can use Postman for this. It's free and easy to understand and use. It is used to test REST APIs.

**https://www.getpostman.com/**

There is an extension available for chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

#### jQuery way

```
$("#reg-form").on("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // Check form data
  console.log($(this).serialize());
  // AJAX
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://192.168.100.11:8443/v1/captive-portal/device-registration",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
         alert(success);
     },

     error: function (jqXHR, status) {
         // error handler
         console.log(jqXHR);
         alert('fail' + status.code);
     }
  });
```

});

#### Your way

Just set `data` as a global variable

```
console.log(document);
var form = document.getElementById("reg-form");

// Data as a global variable
var data = {};

form.onsubmit = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    var input = form[i];
    if (input.name) {
      data[input.name] = input.value;
    }
  }
  addData();
}

function addData(){
 // Check data
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 // AJAX
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://192.168.100.11:8443/v1/captive-portal/device-registration",
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     crossDomain: true,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {

         alert(success);
     },

     error: function (jqXHR, status) {
         // error handler
         console.log(jqXHR);
         alert('fail' + status.code);
     }
  });
}
```